# Xcode, Adding Targets + Settings From One Project Into Another

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I've given the other questions and answers a good look and tried many things, although I'm still confused on how to import Targets along with their respective Build Settings and Build Phases from one project into another project.

**Example**:

[image: Copy Targets with settings to another project]

> <sub>Other questions focus on adding items as "dependencies" in the Build Phase, but that's not what I'm looking to do.</sub>

I'm simply wanting to copy the Targets from Project B into Project A and then I will link them from there, but how? I tried to create a Workspace, but that didn't really work. If someone has some updated information on how to go about this I would appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding everything manually and setting all the settings manually as well.